Why does the apptainer seem to have access to my home directory
I run this command
apptainer exec myfile.sif ls -la /app

and it will correctly show all the files in the container. However, I try
apptainer exec myfile.sif ls -la ~

and it will show all the files in my home directory.
I'm confused. Why is that?  Does the apptainer exec command automatically bind my home directory to the container?

Yes some directories, including $HOME are mounted automatically. See the documentation:

In the default configuration, the default bind mounts are:

The user’s home directory ($HOME)
The current working directory (CWD), unless its path contains symlinks resolving to different locations on the host vs inside the
container.
/dev
/etc/hosts
/etc/localtime
/proc
/sys
/tmp
/var/tmp



Awesome thanks!  That page also says --no-mount will disable this behavior.  Very useful!
